# Change Liferay Search Indexer

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, liferay, portlet

I want  to override the functionality of an indexer and what I found was that the indexer is defined in the liferay-portlet.xml and so I cannot override the indexer unless I changed the file on the server which is a bad practice, so is there anyway I can change the indexer in a good manner ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using 6.0 or higher, you can change the way a document is indexed by using a hook plugin.

Simply define in your `liferay-hook.xml`

```xml
<indexer-post-processor>
    <indexer-class-name>com.liferay.portal.model.User</indexer-class-name>
    <indexer-post-processor-impl>com.example.hook.indexer.UserIndexerPostProcessor</indexer-post-processor-impl>
</indexer-post-processor>
```

In your post processor class extend `com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BaseIndexerPostProcessor` and implement the method you need to change up.

Comment: Is it possible to create an Indexer Post Procesor for a Liferay entity that doesn't have a default Indexer?.. For instance: Layout.

Comment: @moisesbelda unfortunately no.. but.. maybe you can create a hook that contains the indexer and hook the local service or use a model listener to add layout to the index.